# Can the Linux base images for Docker containers be used in environments other than Docker?

Tags: kernel, docker

> Containers share the machine’s OS system kernel

https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container/

If container's share the machine's OS system kernel, is it true that there isn't a kernel included in Docker base images of Linux like Debian or Alpine? Can the [rootfs builds](https://github.com/debuerreotype/debuerreotype) used in these base images be used in environments other than Docker?

The Dockerfile of Alpine Linux shows an example,

```
FROM scratch
ADD alpine-minirootfs-3.14.6-x86_64.tar.gz /
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

Are these builds of Linux assuming anything specific to Docker about the kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it true that there isn't a kernel included in Docker base images of Linux like Debian or Alpine?

That's typically true.  As your reference to alpine shows, they are based on the [mini root filesystem](https://www.alpinelinux.org/downloads/) which do not contain a kernel.

> Can the rootfs builds used in these base images be used in environments other than Docker?

Obviously they can be directly used in other container environments like [podman](https://podman.io/).  And the filesystem they contain can also be used elsewhere.

Taking Alpine as an example, as you show in your question, the docker image is nothing more than the contents of the `alpine-minirootfs-<version>.tar.gz` file.  If you downloaded that file [from here](https://www.alpinelinux.org/downloads/) and untared it you could immediately [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) into the directory to use it as a temporary environment.

```
wget https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/releases/x86_64/alpine-minirootfs-3.15.4-x86_64.tar.gz
mkdir foo
cd foo
tar -xf alpine-minirootfs-3.15.4-x86_64.tar.gz
chroot . /bin/sh
```

*Note `chroot` does not setup all of the isolations such as networking isolation that docker does*

Docker itself packages things in layers so to use a docker image outside of a container environment, like docker or podman, you would need to manually collect the layers back together into one directory tree.

Comment: I ran the code snippet but changed the last line to `chroot . ./bin/sh`.  I'm taking this to mean that this temporary environment is making the same assumptions about its kernel as the host os. Is that accurate?

Comment: @T.Webster Yes.  where the code tries to interact with the kernel (for example through libC) the libraries assume a minimum version of the kernel.  This is the same as binaries on the host OS do.  A very common mistake is to think of docker as a virtual machine; it's not.  Its running the processes natively.  It just swaps out the filesystem and networking etc with a different [namespace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html).

Answer (score 2):

> is it true that there isn't a kernel included in Docker base images of Linux like Debian or Alpine?

Yes; these are *containers*, i.e. they rely on the operating system kernel to do everything. A kernel of their own is no use – it couldn't be run. A container is a Kernel Namespaces thing, not a VM!

> Can the rootfs builds used in these base images be used in environments other than Docker?

Yes, OCI runtimes are standardized. Typically, docker containers do work in podman, and larger orchestration things like kubernetes and similar.

> Are these builds of Linux assuming anything specific to Docker about the kernel?

Yes, kind of: Full Namespace Support. Luckily, that's been around pretty much since Linux 2.6, so that's not very specific.

Of course: All the facilities the programs inside the container use need to be present in the kernel. So, if you have a program inside that uses as syscall or a /sys/ entry introduced in Linux 5.10, then you'll need a Linux 5.10 kernel to run it. But that's the same for any program that you run on any operating system, containerized or not.

Comment: can these [rootfs builds](https://github.com/debuerreotype/debuerreotype) be used in environments other than containers or do they assume anything container-"y" about the kernel?

Comment: I don't know, but it seems likely that if you build something specifically for a container, you wouldn't include stuff like a kernel, supporting module infrastructure, loading infrastructure, an init system … I really don't understand *why* you'd want to use these for anything than a container.